# Connect with RDP download file Error: access Remote Desktop can't connect to the remote computer for one of these reasons

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network, azure-vm

Going through exercises of Fundamentals of Azure, we(me and my team) are unable to connect via our Windows 10 desktops to RDP 3389.

Attached screen-shot.

[image]

Test connections outbound of RDP on the portal work as expected. Connection is successful.
But via clicking "Connect" from the dowloaded RDP file we get this error.

There is section to setup Linux VM via windows; currently exploring that but we see little hope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be various reasons that RDP to Azure VM can fail.
Please check [Troubleshoot Remote Desktop connections to an Azure virtual machine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/troubleshooting/troubleshoot-rdp-connection) section if this helps.
If you just created a new VM in Azure it might be a firewall restriction that is causing the error. You can check if the RDP port 3389 be allowed from your client IP address in the network security group.